# javascript ecma6 convert array items into an object of key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I want to convert an array with some operations into an object of key and value.
Here is my attempt:

```
const config = [ 'key1=value1', 'key2=value2' ];

const configObject = config.map(c => {
  var key = c.split('=')[0];
  var value = c.split('=')[1];
  return  {key:value}
})

console.log('configObject', configObject) // [ { key: 'value1' }, { key: 'value2' } ]
```

I want to obtain an object of key value, rather than an array without any kind of old school **for loop**. like this:

```
{ key: 'value1' , key: 'value2' }
```

Comment: There are for sure some nice array prototypes: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: `key:` => `[key]:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function `reduce`.

```js
const config = [ 'key1=value1', 'key2=value2' ];

const configObject = config.reduce((a, c) => {
  var [key, value] = c.split('=');
  return { ...a, ...{[key]: value} };
}, {});

console.log(configObject);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.reduce` instead

```js
const config = [ 'key1=value1', 'key2=value2' ];

var data = config.reduce(
  (acc, el) => {
    acc[el.split("=")[0]] = el.split("=")[1];
    return acc;
  }, {}
);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. The idiom you're looking for is `Object.assign(...array-of-objects)`:

```js
config = [ 'key1=value1', 'key2=value2' ];

configObject = Object.assign(...config.map(c => {
  var key = c.split('=')[0];
  var value = c.split('=')[1];
  return  {[key]:value}
}))

console.log(configObject)
```

Also note, it's `[key]:`, not just `key:`.

A more concise but perhaps less readable option:

```
configObject = Object.assign(...config
     .map(c => c.split('='))
     .map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could map the splitted key/value pairs in new object and collect all with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) in a single object.

```js
var array = ['key1=value1', 'key2=value2'],
    object = Object.assign(...array.map(s => (([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))(s.split('='))));
    
console.log(object);
```